# Using OpenSimplex for simplex or perlin noise without a seed

Tags: python, 3d, noise, pyopengl, perlin-noise

I'm trying to use perlin or simplex noise on a 3d graphics program in python. I've tried using the "noise" library but it seems to be incompatible. I'm trying to use OpenSimplex, but I want to set things like octaves, persistence, lacunarity, and it only seems to be letting me use a seed. Is there a way to set those things with OpenSimplex without using a seed, or some other library that will let me do this and is compatible with the latest version of python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For perlin noise, you could use the perlin-noise module, which supports setting octaves and the like. As about the seed, you could use the current system time as the seed to make it "random".

perlin-noise module: https://pypi.org/project/perlin-noise/

I would also recommend the module pyfastnoisesimd, it supports both perlin noise  and simplex noise, and is *extremely* customizable (also very fast as in the name).

pyfastnoisesimd: https://pypi.org/project/pyfastnoisesimd/